# How to know the *best* figure dimensions

Tags: floats, dimensions

How do I know which dimensions are best for the figures I want to include in my book? I know about `\textwidth`, `\linewidth`, etc. but is there an automatic way to adjust the figures in an appropriate manner, as some figures will be large, some will be small? Do I have to manually inspect and adjust these settings in `\includegraphics`?

Comment: Try to always include them in original size. If this does not work for single cases, how do you want the algorithm to decide what looks best? This is not possible. Some images are just fine at `\textwidth` but if their original is very small or if it is much higher than wide, it will look ugly. If you know some rule for the program which could make the scaling decision, you should tell us and we help implementing it.

Comment: And as this has been your first post: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 11):

By "best dimensions" I assume  that you are looking for images that *should be scaled* down/up to fit in the width of the column of text,  a minipage or so on ...

One could use the option `scale`  but this imply that you must know in advance the original size without scaling (e.g. 2 x 4 cm) and the desired final size (e.g. 3 x 6 cm) so you can set some like `[scale=1.5]`. But often you give a damn about the original size and you do not want to worry about the final size in absolute units, since this could change with each setting of margins, headers, etc. Anyway, this mean a different scaling for each image, that make difficult some type of automation.

Therefore, often is much better fix a relative width according to the width of the text layout. Although `\textwidth` or `\columnwidth` can be used as lengths of reference, usually is safer `width=\linewidth` in most scenarios. For example a `width=\textwidth` could be fine in a  column of text, as well as `width=\columnwidth` in one or two columns, but not inside a list.  So, a first approach for a general automatic rule could be:

```
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
```

The problem here could be the portrait images that are too big when `width=\linewidth`. In these case you can:

1. Reduce the width manually, e.g.,  `width=.3\linewidth`. The height is then  scaled proportionally.

   `\includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{example-image-a}`
2. Set the height manually to a reasonable value, e.g., `height=10cm`. The width is scaled proportionally.

   `\includegraphics[height=10cm]{example-image-a}`
3. Set the **exact** dimensions of  both `width` and `height` manually. This surely will produce a awful deformed image.

   `\includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth, height=10cm]{example-image-a}`
4. Set **maximum** dimensions of  both `width` and `height`. Juts as above, but adding the option `keepaspectratio`:

   `\includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=\textheight,keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}`

In this case one dimension is not reached to avoid the image distortion, so this do "the best" for any landscape or portrait image. This could work as  a good general rule for most images, as long as the `width` and `height` are reasonable maximum lengths for any case and you admit that some images could have a reduced width. The problem is ... who know what are "reasonable" settings?

As explained at first, for the `width` this might often  `\linewidth` or some fraction of `\linewidth`, and in the same way, for the maximum  height could be `\textheight` or any fraction of `\textheight`, but why not a fixed length in centimeters?.  This always depends on your thoughts. Said that some of your pictures is a long portrait image of 27 cm x 4 cm ... It must fill even the whole column of text, in order to be as wider as possible? It must not be larger than xx cm, even if this reduce the final width considerably?

In the next example, with a document with four columns of text, the `\image` macro limit the image size to with respect the column size  (80% of the width or 20% of the height) so almost any image shape is fitted reasonably well:

[image: MWE]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx,lipsum}
\parskip1em
\usepackage{multicol}
\def\image#1{\begin{center}\includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth,height=.2\textheight,keepaspectratio]{#1}\end{center}}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{4}
\lipsum[1]
\image{example-image-1x1}
\lipsum[2-3]
\image{example-image-a}
\lipsum[4-5]
\image{example-image-16x10}
\lipsum[6-7]
\image{example-image-10x16}
\lipsum[8-150]
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

But why not a 100%-50% or 100-100%?  The "best" fitting rule is a rather questionable issue. As questionable as one like the 80%-20% option could be  equally good for another layout, for instance a two-column text in landscape A4. At last, only the Turing incomplete human brain could find that.

Comment: Great answer! I would just add an entry for the `scale=0.xx` option

Comment: @MarioS.E. Done.