# Scale all figures by the same value

Tags: scaling

In my copy editing work I often need to resize figures to make them fit the pagewidth (remove
"Overfull \hbox..."). I always try to keep the author's layout and the proportion between the figures.

Here's a MWE:

```latex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\overfullrule=1mm
\begin{document}
   
\begin{figure}
  \subfigure[]{\includegraphics[scale=.55]{example-image-a}}\subfigure[]{\includegraphics[scale=.6]{example-image-b}}
  \caption{Image.}

\end{figure}

\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

Below I'll post a solution that I figured out to quickly handle these cases. I'm open to other tips and solutions.

**Clarification.** I begin to suspect that my question isn't clear enough (maybe for my poor english). My solution is focused in keeping the proportions between all the images' size (not the ratio of heigth and width in the single image). I need to scale all figures by the same value as fast as possible.

In the absence of "subfigure" my solution, in this particular case, would have been:

```
\begin{figure}
  \resizebox*{1\textwidth}{!}{\includegraphics[scale=.55]{example-image-a}}\subfigure[]{\includegraphics[scale=.6]{example-image-b}}
  \caption{Image.}

\end{figure}
```

Comment: Why not use the `width` option instead of the `scale` option? For two side by side images you wan chose widths relative to the textwidth. Both widths should add up to q value smaller than or equal to the textwidth.

Comment: I'm a copy editor. I do not write documents by myself and this is a MWE. Using `width` keeping the original proportion of the figures may be very tricky/boring.

Comment: If you just supply the `width` option, the aspect ratio of the image stays unchanged.

Comment: @leandriis I mean the proportion between the two (or more) figures.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My idea is to redefine the `\includegraphics` command inside the `figure` environment:

```latex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\overfullrule=1mm
\begin{document}


\begin{figure}
 \centering
\let\oldincludegraphics\includegraphics
\def\includegraphics#1#{\includegraphicsaux{#1}}
\newcommand*\includegraphicsaux[2]{{\scalebox{.78}{\oldincludegraphics#1{#2}}}}
\subfigure[]{\includegraphics[scale=.55]{example-image-a}}\subfigure[]{\includegraphics[scale=.6]{example-image-b}}
  \caption{Image.}

\end{figure}

\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

You'll need some attempt to find the right scale value... but that's the best I found.

Answer (score 7):

The *scale*, or "natural width", of a graphics file may be of relevance at the time the file was created. E.g., the scale may have been chosen to make the image fit in a certain window on a monitor controlled by the file's creator. Outside of this context, I'd argue that the scale is of little direct relevance for further users or viewers of the image.

Thus, instead of modifying the `scale` parameter of the `\includegraphics` statement, I'd focus on the `width` parameter. E.g., if the objective is to place two equally-wide images side by side, I'd replace

```
\subfigure[]{\includegraphics[scale=.6]{example-image-a}}%
\subfigure[]{\includegraphics[scale=.6]{example-image-b}}
```

with

```
\subfigure[]{\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-a}}%
\subfigure[]{\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-b}}
```

Or, if I also wanted to insert a bit of whitespace -- in the amount of `0.05\textwidth` -- between the images, I might run

```
\subfigure[]{\includegraphics[width=0.475\textwidth]{example-image-a}}\hfill
\subfigure[]{\includegraphics[width=0.475\textwidth]{example-image-b}}
```

Comment: Your example works in the case of figure with the same width (or height...). But how to keep the proportions of figures having different widths expressed, e.g., in cm (and not in a relative factor as \textwidth)?

Comment: I mean the proportion between the two (or more) figures

Comment: @GabrieleNicolardi - The usefulness of my answer is *not* limited to cases where the graphs have the same height or width. (E.g., reset the first width to 0.3\textwidth and the second to 0.7\textwidth and recompile.) If the two graphs must be output at different (relative or absolute) widths, say, 9cm and 6cm, and if they are supposed to span the entire textblock (implying that the width of the text block is 15cm), just set `width=0.6\textwidth` and `\width=0.4\textwidth`, respectively. No trial and error, just set the relative proportions and you're good.

Comment: Sure that your approach will work. But imagine the case of a figure with 10 (or more) images, all with different width, scale or height. Do you think that focusing on the `width` parameter of each image would be faster?

Comment: @GabrieleNicolardi - Nothing is stopping you from writing `width=5mm`, `width=15mm`, etc, is there? Incidentally, I shuddered violently when I contemplated the likely reaction of readers to seeing 10 or more images displayed side by side. Speaking for myself, I would *never* inflict such a typographic calamity on my readers...

Comment: I never told about 10 images side-by-side... They could be in rows of 4, 3, 2 and 1 images... I think that my solution is faster then yours and formally correct but I'm still open to better ideas. (I also think that none of us wants to inflict typographic calamities to its readers but, sometimes, authors have their reasons to keep their layout)

Comment: @GabrieleNicolardi - I think that we've begun to largely talk past each other. I may be taking the view of an author, who doesn't know the width of the textblocks employed by journals and book publishers and hence prefers to think of image widths as *relative widths* -- fractions of the overall available width. You may be taking the view of an editorial specialist of a specific publication, for whom `\textwidth` is fixed constant and for whom it is very natural to think in terms of *absolute widths*. My point is that the `width=...` approach to `\includegraphics` can handle both width types.

Comment: @GabrieleNicolardi:  To set the size of several images of different  dimensions, more or less  automatically, set **both** `width` and `height`   to the **maximum** available  lengths for your taste (always better if they are relative lengths to  `\linewidth` and `\textheight`)  but adding  the **`keepaspectratio`**  option, so that  the image will be  scaled down as needed to adapt to the available space. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/242007/how-to-know-the-best-figure-dimensions.

Comment: @Fran I begin to suspect that my question isn't clear enough (maybe for my poor english). My solution is focused in keeping the proportions between all the images' size (not the ratio of heigth and width of the single image). I need to scale all figures by the same value as fast as possible. I'll edit my question to point it.

Comment: "*scale all figures by the same value*" ...but If that is true, that is conceptually incompatible with "*resize figures to make them fit the pagewidth*" except if all the original images have already the same width. Otherwise, you have not more option that  just  `[scale=<whatever>]`. Moreover, only you can know what `<whatever>`  should be. If the problem is not had to change  `<whatever v1.0>` to `<whatever v 2.0>`  in every image, use  a macro like  `\newcommand\myimg[1]{\includegraphics[scale=<whatever>]{#1}}`  and then you  will need change   `<whatever v1.0>`    only once.